# clipping to bounds with UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill

Tags: iphone, image, uiimageview, clipping

is there any way of controlling where UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill clips an image? In my case, images are always clipped around the center of the image. Is it possible to make it clip around the top?

Thanks!

Antonio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current implementation of `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` is indeed to center the image as you pointed out, to my knowledge there's no way of altering this behavior.